# Time elapsed calculator between two times

Tags: php

```
<input type = "text"  name = "time1" value = "<?php echo   $row['Hours'];  ?>">
<input type = "text"  name = "time2"> 
<input type = "submit"name = "Compute" value = "Compute" >

$calc="";
if(isset($_POST["Compute"]))
{
$time1=$_POST['time1'];
$time2=$_POST['time2'];


$calc = ($time1=$_POST['time1']-$time2=$_POST['time2']);
```

I want to calculate the hours elapsed between two time. For example I entered in textbox1 9:30am then in textbox2 I entered 5:00pm

Answer (score 1):

Use `strtotime` Function

```
( strtotime('12:45:00') - strtotime('11:00:00') ) / 60
```

[In Details](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)